# Disapearing fixed div on window resize

Tags: css, html, fixed

The fixed panel on http://mondaybynoon.com/ disappears, when the window has a width<960.
No JS is used for that.
Can someone explain, how it is implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is use `media query` for that responsive website.

You can define in `HTML` like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```

OR
You can define in `CSS` like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

check these articles for more http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ ,
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 2):

They use the `@media` rule.

Snippet from their CSS:

```
@media (max-width:950px) {
    #sidebar { display:none; }
    #content { margin-left:20px; }
    ...
}
```

Documentation:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width

Answer (score 0):

They use css to do this.  They have rules that say when the browsers width is at this certain width implement this css.